# Создание своего исключения в Yii2

Tags: php, json, yii2, api

) Пишу сейчас API для проекта, для работы с API создал два родительских контроллера от которых наследуются все остальные. В этих контроллерах вызывается метод init(), который получает необходимые данные для дальнейшей работы дочерних контроллеров. Один предназначен для выполнения общедоступных действий, а во втором в init() вызывается метод, который авторизует пользователя. Так вот, проблема вот в чем - когда в родительском контроллере предназначенном для действий требующих авторизацию, вызывается метод, который проверяет данные для авторизации и если данные не верны то кидает исключение. Все работает, но исключение выглядит таким образом:

```
    Array
(
    [name] => Exception
    [message] => Not authenticated!
    [code] => 0
    [type] => api\exceptions\APIErrorException
    [file] => /var/www/a2r2/api/controllers/InternalRestController.php
    [line] => 36
    [stack-trace] ...  
)
```

а мне нужно вернуть в формате JSON и то только две строки

```
  { 
        "Status" : "BAD", 
        "Message" : "Unauthorized" 
  }
```

Перерыл море инфы и не нашел нечего годного(( Может вы что подскажите?

Comment: Метод авторизации из библиотеки используется(в котором происходит возврат ексепшена)?

Comment: Кажется перед исключением надо указать формат ответа сервера \Yii::$app->response->format = \yii\web\Response::FORMAT_JSON; Кстати, подход с двумя контроллерами нарушает принципы SOLID, потом свистопляски начнутся.

Answer (score 0):

Для того, чтобы была возможность кастомизировать сообщение `Exception`, нужно унаследоваться от класса `ExitException`.
Только есть один нюанс.
Вместо сообщение передает массив, обернутый в `json_encode`.